# Where is MySQL database default path in Laravel project?

Tags: mysql, laravel

I create a MySQL database in Laravel using `make:createdatabase` special command  and I create tables in this database but I can't find the database in my project (its path).

Comment: your database should be il your mysql  env.. and this   depend on your OS  ...

Comment: If you didn't create any migration then I am afraid there is no relative path to your database. But you can find your database related configuration in .env or config/database.php file.

Comment: @scaisEdge i see it in env i need to open it to see the tables and data inside it

Comment: @anikislamshojib i created migrations i just need to open it with MySQL to check data

Comment: You can't open migration with mysql they are scripting files. You need some sort of client like sqlyug or workbench

Answer (score 1):

as in  https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database

> Configuration The configuration for Laravel's database services is
> located in your application's config/database.php configuration file.
> In this file, you may define all of your database connections, as well
> as specify which connection should be used by default. Most of the
> configuration options within this file are driven by the values of
> your application's environment variables. Examples for most of
> Laravel's supported database systems are provided in this file.
>
> Laravel makes it very easy to manage your database connections through
>
> ```
> app/config/database.php.
> ```

```
'mysql' => array(
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => 'localhost',
    'database'  => 'database', 
    'username'  => 'root',
    'password'  => '',
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
),
```